# How to accelerate my python looping process for A-star pathfinding?

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, nested-loops, a-star

I try to make an A-star Pathfinding program base on tile-graph (image raster data as graph) where each pixel values represent as cost.. This is my A-star function script so far :

```
def A_star(h,c,dx,dy,u,s_id,e_id,Op,Cl,Prt,CC,o,ht,w):
    Op.append(s_id) 
    while e_id not in Op : 
        if Op == [ ] :
            break
        candidate = { }
        for i in Op :
            d = {i : CC[i]}
            candidate.update(d)
        o = min(candidate, key=candidate.get)
        Cl.append(o)
        Op.remove(o)
        adjacent_list = adjacent_cell(o,dx,dy )
        for p in adjacent_list :
            if p in Cl:       
                adjacent_list = filter(lambda i: i != p, adjacent_list)    
            elif p not in Op :   
                Op.append(p)
                d = {p : o }
                Prt.update(d)
                d = {p : F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)}
                CC.update(d)
            elif id in Op : 
                f1 = F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC) 
                f2 = F(p,Prt[p],h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)
                if f1 < f2 :  
                    d = {p : o }
                    Prt.update(d)
                    d = {id : F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)}
                    CC.update(d)
    return Prt
```

my sample code and input data can be downloaded here 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2zjTfTukbMvaV9BalU4ZGx4MjQ

If i use a small resolution of DEM, 25x29 ( srtm1.tif ), this program goes well. But if i try a large resolution of DEM, for example 1228 x 972 ( dem,asc ). This program took very long time to calculate a whole cell. I guest that the problem is on the looping progress where i try to use loop for iteration (Line 110, A-star function).

```
 while e_id not in Op :
```

Is there any solution to make my code run faster ?
All kind of help, suggestion, comment, solution will be very appreciate..

Comment: And also this code needs gdal and numpy library

Answer (score 0):

some of optimizing will be like this:

```
def A_star(h,c,dx,dy,u,s_id,e_id,Op,Cl,Prt,CC,o,ht,w):
    Op.append(s_id) 
    continu = e_id not in Op
    while continu : 
        if Op == []:
            break
        candidate = {i:CC[i] for i in Op }  # HERE
        o = min(candidate.values())  # HERE
        Cl.append(o)
        Op.remove(o)
        adjacent_list = adjacent_cell(o,dx,dy )
        for p in adjacent_list :
            if p in Cl:       
                adjacent_list = filter(lambda i: i != p, adjacent_list)    
            elif p not in Op :   
                Op.append(p)
                if p==e_id:
                   continu=False # this will stop while from looping!
                Prt[p]=o  # HERE
                CC[p]=F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)  # HERE
            elif id in Op : 
                f1 = F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC) 
                f2 = F(p,Prt[p],h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)
                if f1 < f2 :  
                    Prt[p]=o  # HERE
                    CC[id]= F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)  # HERE
    return Prt
```

using `dict.update` is not for setting one item! use `dict[key]=value` instead.

another help is to check when the `p == e_id` so if it added to `Op` the `while` will stopped!